# Database files not being displayed where SHOW VARIABLES tells me they are

Tags: mysql

Typing SHOW VARIABLES in MySQL will produce show that datadir is = "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data"

...however, looking in the data folder shows only "mysql" and "performance_schema" folders when, in fact, I have made eight databases (including the two previously mentioned ones).

Where is the information from the other databases, like "sakila" being stored?

Comment: Please run `SHOW DATABASES;` and tell us what you see...

Comment: Btw: storing application data in `Program Files` is a bad idea.